# Eclipse subclipse connector error just after 12.04 upgrade

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, svn

Since the 12.04 upgrade, each time I save within eclipse, I get that error :

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Change Sets for SVN Workspace".
>   Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot be loaded.

Subversion and libsvn-java are installed

My eclipse.ini holds the java.library.path arg :

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

But there is no /usr/lib/jni directory...

In Pref > Team > SVN > SVN Connector, I have :

> Cannot load libraries: Could not init class org.tigris.subversion.javahl.svnclient

Any idea ?

Edit

The path for 32 bits is /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ubuntu 12.04 precise pangoline the directory for java.library.path has changed.
I'set "-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni" (on 64 bit installation) in eclipse.ini and i had no more problem

Comment: @Mordred: The splash complaining "javaHL library not found" is not showing anymore. I'm working with Spring STS 2.9.2 (based on eclipse 3.7.2) and subclipse 1.6.x. Are you shure that you not installed the 1.7.x version of sublicpse? In this case you have to downgrade to 1.6.x or to upgrade your subversion OS packages (included javaHL library)

Comment: Thanks a lot. The path for 32 bit ubuntu is /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni

Comment: The 64 bit path is still failing on my 64bit Ubuntu 12.04.  The JavaHL libraries are there, but the error message still occurs with subclipse 1.8 (not with 1.6).